# RestSharp deserializing 401 response to object with default values

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

I've experienced an issue while using RestSharp.

I have a method in my client which is show below. When I send a request with a valid token I get an `IEnumerable` of type `StravaActivityDto`, and its working fine.
But when I send a request and my token is not valid, instead of activities variable being null it is `IEnumerable` of type `StravaActivityDto`, but it always has only one object in it and this has a default value in every property (e.g. `Id`=0, `MaxSpeed`=0).

[image: object]

I have checked the behavior in Postman and if I make a request with an invalid token the status code of the response is 401.

How can I stop RestSharp from deserializing the response if the request is invalid (which results in creating `StravaActivityDto` with default values).
I know I can use `request.Execute` and then check `IsSuccessful` status but I would like to just get null after calling `request.Get<>()`.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<StravaActivityDto>> GetActivities(string token)
{
    var request = new RestRequest("activities", DataFormat.Json);
    request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    var activities = await RestClient.GetAsync<IEnumerable<StravaActivityDto>>(request);

    return activities;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is default behavior of RestSharp, it didn't throw any errors on responses with HTTP errors, only on transport level (when server is unreachable or etc)

So you have 2 options:

**First**

Add **OnBeforeDeserialization** on every request

```
request.OnBeforeDeserialization = response =>
{
     if (!response.IsSuccessful)
          throw new Exception("Response is unsuccessful");
};
```

**Second**

Use **ExecuteGetAsync** instead of **GetAsync** method and check for errors on every response.

```
var response = await client.ExecuteGetAsync<IEnumerable<StravaActivityDto>>(request);
                
if (!response.IsSuccessful)
    throw new Exception("Response is unsuccessful");

return response.Data;
```

also instead of using

```
request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + token);
```

on every requests, you can use JwtAuthenticator (or your custom authenticator if you want) once in client initialization.

```
var client = new RestClient()
{
    Authenticator = new JwtAuthenticator("MyBearerToken")
};
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you:)